# Control.ProductName in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Is there something similar to the following property in WPF?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.productname(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks.

Comment: It is a duplicate, but there is no complete and accurate answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. But you can easily create this method yourself.

The actual code used by WinForms has several levels of fallback: it first look for an `AssemblyProductAttribute` on the assembly defining the control, then at the file version and finally falls back to the first part of the namespace.

You can copy that logic (or the parts that are relevant to you) directly from .net source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs#f7c944851a004a6e